# Homeomorphism between topological spaces defined by $f(x) < g(x)$

Tags: general-topology, functions

So, I have two continuous functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. $f,g : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x$ real.

I have to show that $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R} | f(x) \leq y \leq g(x)\} \cong \mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$.

I imagine I have to figure out a bijective, continuous map with continuous inverse but I am not able to think of one...

Comment: It's always a good idea to start drawing when you have questions like this about sets in the plane. _Always_. If you don't want to (I have no idea why you wouldn't want to, drawing is fun), then can you see how $\{y \mid f(0) \leq y \leq g(0)\}$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yeah, I always draw. It is easy to see that two spaces are homeomorphic "intuitively", but I have trouble when trying to come up with the actual function... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the function $\mu : \mathbb{R}\times [0,1] \to S$ where $S$ is the set you have up there given by
$$
(z,t) \mapsto (z, tg(z) + (1-t)f(z))
$$
It is easy to see that $\mu$ is bijective and continuous. Now define $\psi : S\to \mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$ by
$$
(x,y) \mapsto (x, \frac{y-f(x)}{g(x)-f(x)})
$$
Then check that $\psi$ is continuous and $\psi = \mu^{-1}$